# Can't run java application from site. Could not parse launch file, Error at line 0

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

Trying to open the following link

http://java.net/projects/glazedlists/sources/svn/content/trunk/www/glazedlists-demo.jnlp

I am getting the following error

[image]

Why?

JNLP file is following:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<!-- JNLP File for Glazed Lists demo -->
<jnlp
    spec="1.0+"
    codebase="http://java.net/projects/glazedlists/sources/svn/content/trunk/www/"
    href="glazedlists-demo.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Glazed Lists Demo</title>
        <vendor>Jesse Wilson</vendor>
        <homepage href="index.html"/>
        <description>See Glazed Lists sorting, filtering and transformations in action.</description>
        <icon href="glazedlists-demo.gif"/>
        <!--<icon kind="splash" href="images/splash.gif"/>-->
        <offline-allowed/>
    </information>
    <security>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        <jar href="glazedlists-demo.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.publicobject.issuesbrowser.swing.IssuesBrowser"/>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: My guess is that the file the is on server is on a different encoding that the server understand... Like the server read the file as UTF-8 and you send a file encoded as ISO-8859-1 (just an example)

Comment: It seems that either your file contains not printable character(s) (probably at the first position) or that for some reason you cannot retrieve it using your JNLP URL. Could you check these 2 assumptions? Try to open file using some XML reader to be sure that indeed no extra characters are found there and try to get the content of your jnlp url directly and compare it with your original file.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.geogebra.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=6724) may help you.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).